# Software Center not downloading

Tags: 11.10, software-center, downloads

I just made a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10.
I have a working internet connection, and can browse with Firefox.
But when I try to download things in software center, it says

```
Failed to download package files
Check your Internet connection.
```

and

```
Requires installation of untrusted packages
The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.
```

The "details" are:

```
docbook-xsl dvipng icoutils imagemagick kate-data katepart kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kdebase-runtime kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdoctools kile konsole kubuntu-debug-installer lacheck latex-beamer latex-xcolor libattica0 libcdt4 libclucene0ldbl libdlrestrictions1 libencode-locale-perl libfile-listing-perl libfont-afm-perl libgraph4 libgvc5 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libilmbase6 libio-socket-ssl-perl libiodbc2 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkfile4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkio5 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkmediaplayer4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkparts4 libkpty4 libkrosscore4 libktexteditor4 liblqr-1-0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmagickcore3 libmagickcore3-extra libmagickwand3 libmailtools-perl libnepomuk4 libnepomukquery4a libnepomukutils4 libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libnetpbm10 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libopenexr6 libpathplan4 libphonon4 libplasma3 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libqapt-runtime libqapt1 libqca2 libqt4-designer libqt4-qt3support libqtwebkit4 libsolid4 libsoprano4 libssh-4 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libthreadweaver4 libtimedate-perl liburi-perl libvirtodbc0 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libxml2-utils libxss1 lmodern luatex netpbm ntrack-module-libnl-0 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 oxygen-icon-theme pgf phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer plasma-scriptengine-javascript prosper ps2eps psutils qapt-batch shared-desktop-ontologies soprano-daemon tex-common texlive texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-common texlive-doc-base texlive-extra-utils texlive-font-utils texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended-doc texlive-generic-recommended texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-recommended-doc texlive-luatex texlive-pstricks texlive-pstricks-doc tipa virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common
```

If I run `sudo apt-get update` I get a bunch of "hits", followed by the errors:

```
hits......
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe Translation-en
Fetched 864 B in 4s (198 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Anyone know what's going on?